# PDF: Duplicate font names with different ToUnicode Cmaps

Tags: pdf, unicode

I'm parsing a PDF file and extracting some of the text, and I've run into a situation where I encounter a font dictionary named "C2_0", which contains a CIDFont (Type 0) with a `ToUnicode` CMap.  So, no problem - I have tools to parse the `ToUnicode` CMap and map the 2-byte character codes to Unicode values.

But the PDF file later includes *another* font dictionary object, which is *also* called "C2_0", which contains a *different* `ToUnicode` CMap.  I didn't really how I should handle the second CMap, so I just guessed and combined the entries from both CMaps.  This actually worked, and extracted the text correctly.

But, I can't find anything in the PDF Reference Manual that says this is allowed, or even addresses this situation.  I would have thought that duplicate font names would lead to unspecified behavior, or at least have the second override the first or something.  I only tried combining them as a longshot guess - and was surprised it actually worked.

Does anyone have experience with this?  Does anyone know if a PDF is allowed to have duplicate font names that refer to different objects with different CMaps that "combine" when invoked by a `Tf` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C2_0 is a symbolic name in the /Font resource dictionary and it has local scope, it is used only in the content stream the resource dictionary belongs to. If C2_0 appears also in another /Font resource dictionary, that's not a problem. 
In you have in the same /Font resource dictionary 2 C2_0 entries:
/C2_0 X 0 R
/C2_0 Y 0 R
then you have a problem because the behavior is undefined and it is up to you how to handle the situation.
The symbolic name resolution works like this: if you are in a page content stream, search the font symbolic name (the Tf operand) in the page's resources dictionary. If you cannot locate it, go up in the page tree and search the resources dictionary (if they exist) for each parent page node. If you reached the top of the page tree and you did not find the font, the behavior is undefined. At this moment you can implement various fallback strategies: you can use a default font, you can search the resources included in the form XObjects on the page, you can search the resources dictionaries in the other pages.

Comment: This answer is exactly right. To rephrase, It's fine to have two C2_0 aliases, as long as they are on separate pages. If you have merged pages to a "2up" style, then the merge tool should have resolved the conflicting aliases, renaming one of them. If your two font mappings merge successfully, then you're just lucky.

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunate that you find many PDF files in the wild which are not "perfect"...

What you describe may easily happen if you concatenate 2 PDF files into 1 with tools like `pdftk`.

Duplicate font names not necessarily lead to unspecified behavior -- depending on the cleverness of the PDF reader. The PDF reader can take into account the object ID of each font when rendering the content... or mess it up by relying on fontnames only.